# How to handle large amount of data on the frontend using go template and cassandraDB?

Tags: go

I am using **golang** to load data from CassandraDB and send it to the view component, but it takes almost **2min to load 20k rows of data which is not good for the end-user**.

how to handle this amount of data faster?

This is just an example :

server.go

```
...

var tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    day:=[]string{"Mon","tue","wed","friday"} // huge data from cassandraDB
    tpl.Execute(w, day)
}


...
```

index.html

```
{{range .}}
             
<a>{{.}}</a> <!--Dispay 20k of data-->
             
{{ end}}
```

Comment: Serve the HTML page and use an AJAX request to populate the list. You may even serve the first X records (e.g. 20) with the HTML page so the user can view / work with it wile the rest comes in.

Comment: Where is it spending time? Is it in waiting on receiving the data from Cassandra? Or transforming the data? Or rendering the template? Or sending the response to the client? Or (most likely) a combination of all three? "How do I optimize a web application" is the subject of entire books and impossible to answer here.

Comment: @ icza  I am using dataTable for displaying 10,20,50 rows, however, the data shows after the server.go finishes to iterate through all data in  Cassandra dB

Comment: @Adrian it says that golang is faster but I think here is the server.go that has to go through all the data before sending it to the end-user, so the answer is  in waiting on receiving the data from Cassandra

Comment: Wait, you're displaying 50 or fewer records, but you're pulling 20k from the database? First rule of working with databases is only pull the data you need.

Comment: @ Adrian datatable shows all the data but with pagination `prev 1 2 3 4 5 next` so I don't think that matters, do you? and I even used a simple HTML table, the performance is the same